# What's the best way to install hinges into particle board/chipboard without causing splintering?

Tags: woodworking, hinges, particle-board, cupboard

I have several large particle board/chipboard built-in wardrobe doors (approx 2000mm X 600mm X 20mm). The last person to install them screwed the hinged into the 20mm sides. Over time a lot of the hinges have become loose, some even coming out altogether and taking a good chunk of the chipboard with them.

I've tried very hard to find different hinges that would allow me to screw into the broader front of the door, but there are none that fit my particular situation. Seems like I will have to screw back into the side of the door again.

Are there any tips or tools I can use to secure the hinges and try to prevent this kind of thing happening again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cabinet hinges (as used in kitchen cabinets) are deigned for attachment to MDF and chipboard  this may require redesigning the opening.

gate hinges are designed to attach to the face of the door

screwing into the edge of MDF or chip board ias like screwing into the end grain of real wood so, drill deep pilot holes and use long screws.  really long and deep like 4"  to 5". Also screw short screws in the face to hold the board layers together

Answer (score 1):

Particle board is friable and brittle, *particularly under tension*. By itself, I would not trust a hinge screwed directly into the material.

Under compression, it's stronger, so using a machine bolt and nut, with washers at both ends to spread the pressure, to secure the hinge would be safer. Perhaps you can make, or have made, some flat metal straps with decorative "acorn" nuts to cover the bolts on the outside that might look like part of the cabinet design. The straps would be on top and bottom of the hinge to hold it in place, and to hide some of the missing chipboard.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably install pine battens on the chipboard, and attach the hinges to those. That would help stiffen the panel too.

Then again, I'd avoid chipboard for anything that would ever be seen...